# Connecting a 1TB USB 2.0 WD Elements drive

Tags: linux, kodi, hard-drive, openelec

I've just purchased a Raspberry Pi 3 and I've installed OpenELEC onto the Pi so I can run the Kodi.

After this step - after this first step - I've succesfully set it all up and I've managed to get the USB ports working with a Wi-Fi dongle and also a wireless keyboard. I've also set Kodi to see my movies folder on another NAS.

The problem I have is that Kodi cannot see my external HDD which is plugged into a spare USB port. The HDD is a WD Elements with 1TB of storage and USB 2.0 connection.

The good thing: it has its own power supply. Its got an NTFS file system and this works on my linux machine, my Windows machine and my Linux-Machine.

Well - I guess that I have to use PuTTy into the OpenELEC and try to mount so that I have something like; `/dev/sdb1`

Is there anything else I should do?

Comment: So, did you try to mount it?

Answer (score 0):

Did the same project a while ago , I mounted the drive in my home directory under a folder I created and called "HDD" 
(I dont think its the recommended way to do such things but its how i did ,and in Kodi you can easily navigate to this folder)
(all of this considering you see it in raspbian but doesnt see it in kodi...)
(I guess you installed ntfs-3g)